# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError after changing minSdkVersion

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

After changing minSdkVersion from 21 to 24, i'm receiving exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.DexClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/user/0/com.test.testprint/files/nepcore.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.testprint-2/lib/arm, /data/resource/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libDeviceConfig.so"
```

After switching back to minSdk 21, everything back to work.

I also tried to add ndk filters, was not helpful :(

Can anybody help to understand how this exception connected with minSdkVersion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Was needed to add one line in manifest file, inside application section :)

```
<application
  ...
android:extractNativeLibs="true">
```

Comment: You saved my DAY! Thank you very much. But I am still wondering why we need to declare android:extractNativeLibs="true" while Google's docs describes that the attribute is set to "true". In addition, my test phone was "Galaxy S10e" with "Android 12".

Comment: Thx you!!! You advice was very helpfull.

Comment: Dude you deserve a bounty

Comment: @Yevhen. This is not working for me. Can you please help me  ?
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.DexClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/user/0/com.samplepaymentpos/files/nepcore.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sample.paymentpos-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /data/resource/lib]]] couldn't find "libDeviceConfig.so"

I have tried adding .so files in libs folder as well and jniLibs folder as well. But nothing is working for me :(

Answer (score 2):

For minSdk >= 23 and Android Gradle Plugin >= 4.2.0, need to use [useLegacyPackaging](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/JniLibsPackagingOptions#uselegacypackaging) in app's build.gradle file instead of [extractNativeLibs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#extractNativeLibs) in Androidmanifest.xml

Sample usage of DSL to package compressed native libraries (can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#compress-native-libs-dsl))

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging true
        }
    }
}
```